# Alguém tem ideia de como o google drive descompacta arquivo em tempo real

Tags: php, google-drive-api, stream-de-arquivos

Queria entender e saber se há alguma biblioteca ou estratégia para fazer o mesmo que o Google Drive faz com os arquivos comprimidos, de permitir navegar pelos arquivos do interior do arquivos sem ter que descompacta-los.

Alguém tem ideia de como se faz isso?

Comment: Tudo é feito em temporário. Você na verdade descompacta em temporário e percorrer os arquivos, retornando a arvore do arquivo, se algum arquivo for requisitado, você recupera pelo temporário.

Comment: humm, vc tem ideia de como fazer isso sem ter que escrever em disco? algo em memória?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar alguma biblioteca que faz a leitura de arquivos Zips. O próprio PHP tem essas funções como:

- [Zip Open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.zip-open.php)
- [Zip Read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.zip-read.php)

Comment: No entanto para utilizar essas funções é necessário salvar o arquivo em disco. Gostaria de fazer em memória. Imagina receber o arquivo compactado em base64 e extrair os dados dele (arquivos dentro do arquivo compactado) em memória...